# Android change google map markers icon on click

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to change the marker icon in google map on click . I can do it easily by overriding `onMarkerClick`

```
  @Override
  public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_selected_user_mark_icon));

        return true;
    }
```

But the problem is, lets say I have already clicked a marker which icon is already changed . When I click another marker it's icon also changed . What I actually want only clicked marker has a different icon . And the others will have same.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Save last clicked marker, and on second click restore it's icon to default

```
Marker lastClicked = null;
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    if (lastClicked!=null)
        lastClicked.setIcon(<defaultIcon>);
    marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_selected_user_mark_icon));
    lastClicked = marker;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , nice solution

Comment: Very Nice Solution.